# Запрет на перенос строк

Tags: android, java

Как в `TextView` запретить перенос текста, который не помещается, на новую строку?

Comment: пользоваться Label??

Comment: Такого класса нет в библиотеке.

Comment: TextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
textview.setMaxLines(1);
```

Comment: Это то же самое, что и `singleLine="true"`?

Comment: это немного другое
singleLine="true" ставит многоточие, а
textview.setMaxLines(1); просто обрезает

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/numText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если необходим запрет переноса строки то используйте `android:singleLine="true"`

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:maxLines="1"
        **android:singleLine="true"** />
```